# Ionic+Firebase: Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]

Tags: javascript, ionic, firebase, typescript

Eu sou nova em ionic e estou enfrentando um problema, tenho essa aplicação que trabalha com câmera/galeria, e acredito que o erro esteja no arquivo .ts eis o código:

```
save(animal) {
      this.dbService.save(animal).then(
        response => {
          // ALERT DE QUE FOI SALVO COM SUCESSO
          let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
          let imageRef = storageRef.child('image').child(response.key);

          imageRef.putString(this.animal.fotoAtual, 'data_url')
            .then(snapshot => {
              console.log(snapshot)
            }, err => {

          })
          this.toastrService.show('Registro realizado com sucesso!', 3000).present();
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(ListPage);
        },
        error => {
          // ALERT DE QUE DEU ERRO NA FUNÇÃO
        }
      ), (r => console.log(r));
      }
```

no caso na minha aplicação eu tenho um provider que centraliza o crud da aplicação, ai nela eu tenho o método save que está assim:

```
save(animal: any){
   return this.dbRef
        .push(animal);
  }
```

agradeço desde já

Comment: Boa noite, o log completo do erro é apenas o titulo ou tem mais? Se tiver ajuda.